# angularjs: can't install angular-cookies to my project

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I my project I came into an issue about the package of angular-cookies.

I have download the package and place it in my project. And as usually, in index.html, I add a script tag:

`<script src="vendor/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>`

But when the pages loaded I got an error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: c.module(...).info is not a function at angular-cookies.min.js:7`

in the package, it uses `angular.module.info` but it is not regarded as a function?

So what is the reason for this issue? Is it because version issue? Any help

Comment: what version of angular and angular-cookies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a recent bower update I've done. I don't know if the angular 1.6.3 is stable so I went to https://code.angularjs.org/latest/ and I saw that is 1.5.8 angular version which is used.

So to resolve it, I added these versions in my bower.json :

"dependencies": {
    "angular-cookies": "1.5.8",
},

"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8"
}

Answer (score 0):

You should install particular dependecies according to angular.You can achieve it by using bower install like this:

```
bower install angular-cookies@1.5.8

bower install angular@1.5.7
```